# mysql last month date statement

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a DATE, how do I write a `where` that checks for last month until now (either the first of or just today's day -1 month)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateField > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

This selects all rows that have a `dateField` more recent than current timestamp minus one month (so, for example, given today is 26 Sep 2009 00:56 it would give rows that are more recent than 26 Aug 2009 00:56)

Answer (score 12):

Actually, last month until now would be:

From the beginning of the month:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
AND date <= NOW()
```

Since a month ago: (hopefully you have no future dates on the table)

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Alternatively, you might want only the last month... Say today is September and you want all August, not including any of September... That is what I understand as 'last month'.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01')
AND date < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01')
```

You could also do for the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```