# grab all rows but the last month in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is a query to get all rows in the past month.

```
$time = time() - 9676800;

$q = $this->db->query("
    select id
    from ipAddress
    where date > {$time}
");
```

But how can i adjust this query to get all rows BESIDES the past month? Basically I want to end up deleting all rows over 1 month old

Comment: What platform are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Your requirements are very vague. Please improve them.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your methodology for calculating "last/past month" satisfies you, then it's simple:

`where date <= {$time}`

Comment: my methodology does not satisfy me. I need to get all rows more than 1 month old

Comment: Then **why on earth** didn't you say so more clearly? Just **look** at your post for one teensy minute. Given your sample code, it *seems* obvious that the problem is your lack of understanding about greater-than `>` and less-than `<`. If the method you're using of subtracting 9676800 isn't what you want, **say so**. "Past month" and "last month" are very vague! Seriously, your question is extremely poor quality. What is 1 month to you--30 days? The last completed calendar month? The same day number in the prior month as the current month? We are not mind readers. Specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_format, date_sub functions to get last month's dates.
Find answers here:
[mysql last month date statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479745/mysql-last-month-date-statement)
and here
[MySQL Query to calculate the Previous Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138190/mysql-query-to-calculate-the-previous-month)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so

```
$time = strtotime('-1 Month');

$q = $this->db->query("
    select id
    from ipAddress
    where `date` <= {$time}
");
```

but if `date` is a TIMESTAMP, DATE, or DATETIME string like `2013-02-27 22:16:38` or `2013-02-27` then you need something like

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 Month'));

$q = $this->db->query("
    select id
    from ipAddress
    where `date` <= '{$time}'
");
```

Or purely in SQL

```
select id
from ipAddress
where `date` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

And if I remember correctly, `date` is a reserved mysql word so use backticks in your sql.

Comment: This gives me the same result as my example. My example gets all rows in the past month. I want all rows BESIDES the past month. Basically I want to end up deleting all rows over 1 month old

Comment: No it shouldn't. See this SQL fiddle for proof: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e556c/3