# Select data from last month sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to select from my database data from current month:

```
SELECT * FROM daily_reports
WHERE username = '$username' and MONTH(date) = MONTH(Now())
order by date DESC
```

And now i want to display data from last month.

column date is type date

Comment: Note: This will give you data from the current month in EVERY year

Comment: `MONTH(date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))`

Comment: I definetly think this could help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479745/mysql-last-month-date-statement

Comment: Try searching before asking, there are a lot of answers for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:-

```
SELECT *
 FROM daily_reports 
WHERE username = '$username' 
and MONTH(date) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
 order by date DESC
```

Comment: make use of BETWEEN in your statement.

Comment: This will also give you data from the specified month from EVERY year where data is available.

Comment: To get only data from a single month add `AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM daily_reports 
WHERE username = '$username' 
and MONTH(date) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) order by date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  daily_reports 
WHERE username = '$username' 
  AND dateColumn BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW();
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do many operations on dates, as shown in the fine manual.

In your case, perhaps the [DATE_SUB function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) would be clearest:

```
SELECT * FROM daily_reports
WHERE username = '$username' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date BETWEEN date_format
(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') 
AND last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```