# Query By Last month SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return this squery by last month.

My table **service_total** as a field **date_time** , i want to use that one.

I am search about this and try many ways. But i was not able to get a correct syntax.

```
SELECT service_total.total_shipments , partner.name
FROM service_total
INNER JOIN partner 
ON partner.short = service_total.partner_short
WHERE partner.local = '0' 
ORDER BY service_total.total_shipments DESC
LIMIT 5
```

EDIT ------------

The query about is correct , but i expect to return only the values from last month.

Imagine in table **service_total** i have 2 rows. One is from December and one from January. Since its February i want only the row from January.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you need would really help.

Comment: Could you please put sample data and expected output? Your query looks OK. Do you have total_shipments column in the original table or you need to calculate it in the query? If second, then you need to use "group by "

Comment: Check my edit pls, thanks :D

Comment: "I want to return this squery by last month." `WHERE partner.local = '0'  AND date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`  ? if that does not work or does not give expected results you should provide example data and expected results.. [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) like @GordonLinoff suggested

Comment: ... where ... and date_time = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479745/mysql-last-month-date-statement

Comment: yes but your query will most likely will not match anny records with `=` operator @ErayBalkanli mine query should have been `WHERE partner.local = '0' AND date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` offcource.. MySQL allows this syntax.

Comment: Can you please provide as an answer and not a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include in your statement these conditions:

```
  YEAR(date_time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND 
  MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

So:

```
SELECT service_total.total_shipments , partner.name
FROM service_total
INNER JOIN partner 
ON partner.short = service_total.partner_short
WHERE 
  YEAR(date_time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND 
  MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  
  AND
  partner.local = '0'  
ORDER BY service_total.total_shipments DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is only returning from the last 30 days, i want from the previous month.

Comment: No it does not return the last 30 days. It returns only the **previous month**.

Comment: This: `MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` guarantees that the rows have `date_time` only of the previous month (combined with `YEAR(date_time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`). Try it.

Answer (score 0):

use   `date_time` in where condition

```
 SELECT service_total.total_shipments , partner.name
    FROM service_total
    INNER JOIN partner 
    ON partner.short = service_total.partner_short
    WHERE partner.local = '0'  and date_time >= date(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ORDER BY service_total.total_shipments DESC
    LIMIT 5
```